# Confusion about creating a standalone client for an existing Java enterprise application project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have access to a Java enterprise application project. In this project there is an EAR file that contains an EJB project, a dynamic web project for web services which makes calls to the EJB project and finally a web client project. The EAR is deployed on a JBoss WildFly app server. However, I would like to create a standalone client using JavaFX for this project. After researching old S.O. posts (yes, I read other posts before I asked the question but none of them addressed my concerns clearly enough) and using Google I was only able to find outdated examples. I am confused about the following related topics:

1) In order to access the classes from the existing EJB project do you have to create *copies* of the remote interfaces in the standalone client app which are already in the EJB project? (This feels wrong to me)

2) If you add the EJB project to your client's classpath, won't this create compile time errors because the client code will not have access to the server code when they run the client application?

3) Eclipse has an option to create an EJB Client project whenever you create a new EJB project. This automatically adds the remote interfaces in the clients code, leaving no remote interface on the server side. Is this acceptable? For arguments sake, what if you want a client in Swing and a client in FX? They would both need to use the remote interfaces, so I imagine you'd have to have a project that contained the remote interfaces and then a project for each client that had references to the project containing the interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a huge JavaFX guy, so I'm not going to answer all of the questions here. However, 1.) is a fairly easy fix.

Pull your interfaces out of your EJB jar into their own jar, and add this as a dependency to both the EJB and the client. If you're using Maven or Gradle (and if you're not, you should be asking yourself why you aren't), you can include building this 'API' jar within the same project so that you don't have the annoyance of treating these interfaces as a separate project. For example, in Maven a common approach to this would be to have two modules for your EJB stuff: 'somethingsomething-api' and 'somethingsomething-ejb'. Maven's multi-module functionality allows you to build these items together but package them separately, which is important when you'd like to bundle just your interfaces and beans with another item like a client, but don't want/can't have all of the other goodies you'd have in your EJB jar getting pulled into your client, etc.

Comment: I am going to figure out how to get Maven configured and go this route. Thanks for the confirmation.